Vue js with Express
how can i use Vue JS with Node js express.
Hello,
How can I integrate Vue.js with a Node.js Express server?
I want my Node.js server to provide data to my Vue.js site or for the Vue.js front end to send data to my server. However, I am uncertain about the correct location to place my Express app.js file within the project structure. Could you please guide me on how to properly organize my files so that the Express server and Vue.js front end can communicate effectively? Thank you!

Broad, opinion-based questions are offtopic on SO. These are two unrelated NPM projects that run in different environments. You can manage them the way you want. "communicate effectively" - they communicate through HTTP protocol, this makes the way their files are related irrelevant. You can make them sibling subfolders if you must if you need to keep them in the same repo, but that's all

How can i make them communicate with each other?

As said, through http protocol, that's the purpose of setting up an express server. You run it as app.listen(3000) in node app.js and do requests to http://localhost:3000/... with fetch(), axios or anything else in vue app

my expectation you already know how to initiate project on both side but dont know how to integrate it.
I could give a response depending on your requirements..
for me, it's better to spread it into 2 projects.
if using monolith for medium - large scale projects,
need to create optimal scaffolding from scratch, if not it is like snowballing over time.
if you want to create 2 projects and consume API,
for frontend needs HTTP request library such as axios to communicate
make sure you set up your env like baseURL and port match with your backend.
here how to use axios
https://axios-http.com/docs/example
if your vue project want to use state management,
here the documentation
https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html
place your HTTP request using axios inside action.
